# UITableView - how to not dump/reload cells while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my table view cells I am loading thumbnails remotely, so when I scroll, the thumbs disappear and there is an empty spot while they load each time. I'd just like to load them all once and not have them keep disappearing and reappearing when I scroll. I only have 15-20 cells total so I don't think this should be a problem. How can I turn off the unloading of cell data when they scroll off screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to keep a reference to the thumbnail objects (for example, in an NSArray), and reuse them.  First query the array, and if it doesn't exist load it from the remote location and place it in the array at the desired position.  If it does exist, then use it from there.